# Как спроектировать класс в С++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, нужно написать программу склад. Например, диски бывают CD и DVD. Независимо от типа диска, его содержимым может быть: музыка, видео, ПО.

Нужно ли создавать два класса или это возможно сделать по другому?

```
class CD {
   public:
        enum Type {
              music, video, PO
                };
};

 class DVD {
       public:
            enum Type {
                  music, video, PO
                };
};
```

Comment: лучше один класс. Если все параметры одинаковы. Тип дисков сделайте отделным классом и все

Answer (score 5):

Классы пишут когда надо инкапсулировать (выделить в отдельное место) какое-то поведение. Классы в программировании - это в первую очередь код с методами которые что-то делают, а не просто отображение сущностей из предметной области.

По этому если у CD и DVD дисков одинаковое поведение, то для них нужен один класс, возможно с разными значениями полей.

```
enum class Content { Music, Video, /* ... */ };

class OpticalDisk {
public:
  enum Kind { CD, DVD, BD };

  ???
private:
  Kind kind_;
  Content content_;
};
```

Но возможно, что у классов CD и DVD дисков вообще нету поведения. Тогда не надо делать их классами, сделайте обычную структуру данных

```
struct OpticalDisk {
  enum Kind { CD, DVD, BD };

  Kind kind;
  Content content;
};
```

Comment: а между классом и структурой есть какая-то разница в представлении данных?)

Comment: Плюсую. Подход, когда Data и Control разнесены, как показывает опыт, почти всегда выигрышный. Не знаешь, как лучше - разноси. Данные в struct, управление в отдельный класс с методами.

Comment: Тип  `Content` является тоже перечислимым (музыка, видео, ПО), можно ли создать `enum Content {music, video, PO};` ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать композицию

```
class Types 
{
    public:
        enum DataTypes {music, video, PO};
        enum DiskTypes {CD, DVD};

        DataTypes DataType;
        DiskTypes DiskType;
}

class Disk
{
    public:
        Types Type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вид диска запихнуть так же в перечисление, таким образом можно создать один класс.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно замутить две параллельные иерархии классов: носитель данных (media) и тип данных (data):

```
class Data {
public:
    virtual ~Data() {}
};

class Media {
    Data* data; 
public:
    Media(Data* d) : data(d) {}
    virtual ~Media() {}
};

class Music : public Data {
};

class Video : public Data {
};

class DVD : public Media { 
    using Media::Media;
};

class CD : public Media { 
    using Media::Media;    
};

int main()
{
    Media* m = new DVD(new Video);
}
```